# No markdown on review of Low Quality Posts, and Edit fails review

Tags: feature-request, review, markdown, review-audits, low-quality-posts

Sometimes rendered output isn't enough to review a post.

From the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) review queue, there's no way to review markdown which is sometimes necessary to perform a review.

Reviewing low quality posts, I stumbled upon [this gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22746135/798448):

> [image: post]

Doubting there was anything salvageable, I wanted to review markdown before hastily recommending deletion.  Upon selecting edit, I [failed the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4644923).

> [image: review]

To me, it looks like the user is experiencing issues with markdown - I want to see what they're attempting to link, or maybe quote, maybe there's html entities being filtered leaving only some script... it's hard to even tell why this is spam until you see the markdown:

> [image: markdown]

If review audits are going to fail on edit, then there should be ability to view markdown.

Comment: Ha! I got that same review audit today myself! +1 for markdown. Choosing edit for spam should reasonably be an audit failure, but only if you've verified it really is spam.

Comment: Catch 22: the low quality queue doesn't actually have a spam option. You have to visit the actual post to flag as spam. There is no appropriate action within review

Comment: +1 for "there should be ability to view markdown."